# Is it possible to get notice when user connects to my share?

Tags: windows-7

When I share some folders on network, I can see users connected to me and who has which file opened in Computer->Manage.

Is it somehow possible to see a notice when a new user connects to me?

Is there a piece of software that would show me a popup window?

Is there a solution for Windows 7?

Comment: In the folder security window (under Advanced) is a tab "Audit", in which you can set it to record events to Security log every time an object is accessed. (Use the `NETWORK` group to only log access through the network.) While this won't get you popup windows, you will at least be able to follow the log in Event Viewer (`eventvwr.msc`).